# Macro for struct members

Tags: c

I have a struct definition that I am not allowed to change. However, I would like to access a member after doing an operation on it (the operator appears after the first operand). It occurred to me that I could use a macro to access the modified value as if it were part of the struct itself.

```
struct test{
    int a;
    int b;
} *t;

#define c b+1
...
printf("%d", t -> c);
```

This does look nicer to me, but it feels like something could go wrong with replacement. Is there a better way to do something like this? Is this bad practice? What can go wrong?

Comment: Don't. Just don't. "Unreadable unsupportable mess" doesn't even begin to cover it...

Comment: Not clear what you try to accomplish or why a macro looks "nicer" for your. Even without considering replacement problems, it looks actually awful. Don't get too fancy with macros! (oh, and you never should use single-letter macros outsidde a very limited portion of the source file).

Comment: Always, always, use parentheses around a macro definition. What do you suppose `printf("%d", t -> c * 3);` will do.

Comment: @WeatherVane the catch is, in this case parentheses can't be added.

Comment: which is a clear sign of 'dont do this evil thing'

Comment: @Quentin *It occurred to me that I could use a macro* so if it was your idea you can position the cursor and type the parentheses. Otherwise scrap the idea. You also asked *What can go wrong?*

Comment: @Quentin oh sorry, I was replying as if you were the OP. I see now that the parentheses will not do any good.

Comment: The dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not have spaces on either side in normal code.

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone. I was just doing some crazy experiments with structs and bit operations on fields, so I was just testing stuff on the surface. I see now that it is an extremely bad idea :D

Comment: @WeatherVane aaaargh! Don't shoot the messenger! :D

Answer (score 1):

> *What can go wrong?*

```
printf("%d", t->c * 3);
```

For starters.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is bad.

1. Single letter members and macros (but let's ignore that)
2. Hard to read and support. (is `t->c` a member or one of those crazy marcros I added? Was `c` +1 or -1?

If you really have to macro-ize it for some reason, then make it clearer.

e.g.

```
#define BPlusOne(t) ((t)->b + 1)
printf("%d", BPlusOne(t));
```

If it's just a simple piece of work for school this is overkill, but I'm currently working on a big system where the structs are generated as are all of these type of macros, and in this case it works (but I still wouldn'thave done it this way ;-)